# Como repetir accion al elegir la misma opcion del spinner

Tags: spinner

Tengo un Spinner con 3 opciones: Seleccionar, Opción 1 y Opción 2.
En cada opción se realiza determinada acción.
Si por ejemplo eligo la opción 2 el texto del Spinner se queda como "Opción 2" y eso es bueno porque quiero que el usuario sepa en que opción está, pero el problema viene cuando quiero volver a seleccionar la opción 2 ya que toco el spinner, se muestran sus elementos pero al seleccionar la misma opcion en la que está posicionado no hace nada, ya que piensa que la acción ya está ejecutada pero la quiero volver a ejecutar desde el spinner.

La opcion 2 se vuelve a ejecutar solamente si pongo opcion 1 y despues de vuelta opcion 2, pero es mucho lío.

Quizá una alternativa sería poner la posición en 0 con spinner1.setSelection(0); pero como dije antes quiero que el spinner tenga el texto de la opcion en la que estas entonces no vale cambiarle la posicion al elegir la opcion.

En resumen lo único que quiero es que desde el spinner ejecute la acción al repetir una misma opción

Answer (score 0):

Y si usas dos spinners, el primero se mantiene con la opción seleccionada, pero cuando vayas a elegir otra opción utilizas el segundo spinner, para cuando vayas a elegir otra opción spinner1.setSelection(0) y eliges una en el spinner 1, y para el segundo spinner2.setSelection(0). Creo que puedes sacar una solución haciendo algo así.

Comment: Gracias por responder,creo que lo que dices tampoco funciona ya que cuando se oculte el primer spinner y se muestre el segundo hay que ponerlo en una posición que contenga el mismo texto que el primer spinner pero al presionar el segundo spinner no puedes seleccionar la misma opción ya elegida y pues es el mismo problema, pero ya lo resolví creando un falso spinner, al elegir una opción del spinner se oculta y se muestra un botón blanco con el texto de la seleccion y esta flecha al final ▼, al cliquear el botón se oculta el botón y se muestra el spinner y se expande con spinner.performClick();